# Front-end CSS Library for plugin

Tags: plugins, css, front-end, library

I'm looking for a CSS library that can style elements I display on the client-side (front-end) of a wordpress website. The CSS library needs to be able to work with most of the wordpress themes, which means it just has a list of classes I can use, and doesn't alter the themes' global style (see below for explanation).

The problem with the libraries I've come across is that they alter the global style of a theme. For example they style the body tag with a background color, they edit the fonts and sizes of h1, h2, h3 etc tags. Another part of the problem is *normalize.css*, it tends to break themes.

So far I've tried:

- Bootstrap
- Bootflat
- Foundation
- Pure-io (too few styling options)
- Topcoat

In short: I'm looking for a CSS library which doesn't alter any elements unless I attach a class to those elements. This way I can build a plugin which doesn't break theme styles.

Are there any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieving unaltered style via plugin for multiple themes is pretty difficult to achieve.

How about this?

Use any library among these e.g. Bootstrap in your plugin and then remove/comment the global properties from them.

Since you will be author of the plugin, you can repeat the same thing in your plugin before releasing next update.

Comment: Thanks! I've gone with extracting the styles I need, and so far it's been working out quite nicely :)
P.S. Sorry mods, I didn't know the product recommendation rule